# automapper date/time into a date and a time json c#

Tags: c#, json, datetime, automapper

Date/Time into a date and time field.

DB Class

```
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
```

VM Class

```
    public DateTime ValidFromDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ValidFromTime { get; set; }
```

I tried automapping:

Pushing out

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ValidFromDate, src => src.MapFrom(m => m.ValidFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) 
.ForMember(dest => dest.ValidFromTime, src => src.MapFrom(m => m.ValidFrom.TimeOfDay))
```

Pulling in

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ValidFrom, src => src.MapFrom(m =>
DateTime.Parse(m.ValidFromDate.Contains("T") ?
m.ValidFromDate.Remove(m.ValidToDate.LastIndexOf("T",
StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1) : m.ValidFromDate + " " +
m.ValidFromTime)));
```

However this throws an error, datetime not recognised

I've noticed I cab do something like this: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" });`

But wondering how I handle the time bit?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you have? IE When you say "datetime not recognized", what exactly are you seeing?

Comment: `HolidayDate` doesn't exist in the classes you have shown, which has `ValidFromDate` - and the type isn't clear, is that a datetime (as in the class) or a string (as in the mapping)?